# Is there a second DNS server for GitHub pages with custom domains?

Tags: github, dns

[Setting up a custom domain with pages](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-pages) instructs users to set up a DNS A Record to point to 204.232.175.78 in order to use a custom domain with their GitHub pages.

However, at 101domain.com, it tells me: You need to specify atleast 2 name servers. 101domain won't let me specify the same name server twice.

Thus, is there a second DNS server for GitHub pages with custom domains? Most hosts offer between 4 or 6 DNS servers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're specifying the wrong thing.

You need to set an **A record** with an existing DNS provider; GitHub does not give you a nameserver.

Comment: Thanks! That's my mistake. Any good DNS providers you can recommend for this purpose? (I always use Zerigo DNS add-on when I use Heroku)

Comment: @ilias: Most registrars include DNS servers.  You can also use Amazon Route53 or DNSimple.